# ImageGrab not grabbing precise bbox image

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i tried using using `pygetwindow` and `ImageGrab` to get the location of a window and take a snap of it, but i am getting kind of the correct image but also some extra pixels from the sides. Subtracting some pixels from the size is also not helping. Am i doing anything wrong or is there a better and easier way to do? Also tried using `win32gui` but getting same output as image

CODE:

```
import pygetwindow as gw
from time import sleep
from PIL import ImageGrab

win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Health Card')[0]
winleft = win.left
wintop = win.top
winright = win.right
winbottom = win.bottom
sleep(3)
print(win.left,win.right,win.bottom,win.top)
a = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(winleft,wintop,winright,winbottom))
a.save('hey.png')
```

IMAGE:

[image]

How can i get, just the window precisely and exclude the title bar of the window too

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: It's probably some pesky drop-shadow or window *"decoration"*. Try capturing a few differently sized windows and see if it is a constant size border, then just always subtract that many pixels on the appropriate side. Or look for documentation on your grab function and see if there is an option to exclude shadows or decorations.

Comment: @MarkSetchell oh ya it cud b shadows of the window, but i tired subtracting, no help on it, jus gets some diff sizes, i dotn think documentation has a way either :(

Comment: yes @MarkSetchell i after long search i got a result for c++ i think, now ive solved it by subtracting the shadow border :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to the windows shadow applied to the GUI in Windows 10.

Here is how I fixed it for `pygetwindow`:

```
import pygetwindow as gw
from PIL import ImageGrab
from time import sleep

win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Health Card')[0]
winleft = win.left+9
wintop = win.top+38
winright = win.right-9
winbottom = win.bottom-9

sleep(3)
a = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(winleft,wintop,winright,winbottom))
a.save('trial.png')
```

Or if you are using `win32gui` then try

```
from win32gui import FindWindow, GetWindowRect
from time import sleep
from PIL import ImageGrab

win = FindWindow(None, 'Health Card')
rect = GetWindowRect(win)
list_rect = list(rect)
list_frame = [-9, -38, 9, 9]
final_rect = tuple(map(lambda x,y:x-y,list_rect,list_frame)) #subtracting two lists

sleep(3)
a = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=final_rect)
a.save('trial.png')
```

Ive used `map()` to subtract both the lists, you can use any method you like(eg:`numpy`).

**Final Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**
Usually the border is only for left, right and bottom i have removed the title bar too and im using `+` cuz of the axis difference. This is almost equivalent to cropping. I think the standard size of window shadow is 7px so we have to remove something like 7-10px for accuracy

Comment: Well done - thank you for sharing your findings back with the SO community. You can accept your own answer and grab the points, by the way.