# Is there a way to capture the contents of a Tkinter canvas into an image?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to build a handwritten digit recognition system, using convolutional neural networks. So far, I have developed a Tkinter window that contains a canvas, on which you can hand-write a digit. After I hit the 'Recognize' button, I want the program to take an image of that digit (i.e. the canvas) and run it through the neural network to predict the digit. The following is an implementation of some code I found online:

```py
from tkinter import *
import win32gui
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

cv = Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg='white', cursor='cross')
cv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

hwnd = cv.winfo_id()
cv_rect = win32gui.GetWindoRect(hwnd)
img = ImageGrab.grab(cv_rect)
```

This code is able to grab an image. However, the image isn't of the canvas, but somewhere else on the screen, usually to the north-west of the canvas. The output looks something like this:

[image]

However, if I move the Tkinter window further away from the top left of my computer screen, the image doesn't even capture the top left of the Tkinter window, as in the above image.

For further perspective, here is the whole code of the file in which I am building this gui.

```py
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab
import win32gui
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import win32api

cnn = tf.keras.models.load_model('\\Users\\hamza\\Documents\\VS Code\\mnist.h5py')

#---------------------------------------------------------------
'''
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)

X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_test /= 255

y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

y_pred = cnn.predict(X_test)
print(y_pred[3700])
print(y_test[3700])

test_eval = cnn.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

print('Test loss:', test_eval[0])
print('Test accuracy:', test_eval[1])
'''

from pyscreenshot import grab
import pygetwindow as pgw
'''
im = grab(bbox=(500, 200, 800, 400))
im.show()
'''


def predict(img):
    #img = img.resize((28, 28))
    img = img.convert('L')
    img = np.array(img)
    #img.reshape(28, 28)
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=matplotlib.cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')
    plt.show()
    #img = img.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)/255
    #pred = cnn.predict(img)[0]
    #print(pred)
    #print('---------------------')
    #return np.argmax(pred), max(pred)

def classify():
    '''
    hwnd = cv.winfo_id()
    print(hwnd)
    cv_rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
    img = ImageGrab.grab(cv_rect)
    '''
    win = pgw.getWindowsWithTitle('tk')[0]
    winleft = win.left+9
    wintop = win.top+7
    winright = win.right-9
    winbottom = win.bottom-9
    final_rect = (winleft,wintop,winright,winbottom)
    img = ImageGrab.grab(final_rect)
    
    digit, accuracy = predict(img)
    print(digit)
    print(accuracy)
    #label.configure(str(digit) + ', ' + str(int(accuracy*100)) + '%')
        
def clear():
    cv.delete('all')
    
def draw(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    r = 8
    cv.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, fill='black')

root = Tk()

cv = Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg='white', cursor='cross')
cv.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=2, sticky=W)

label = Label(text='Welcome', font=('Helvetica', 32))
label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)

clear_button = Button(text='Clear', command=clear)
clear_button.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2)

recognize_button = Button(text='Recognize', command=classify)
recognize_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=2, pady=2)
        
cv.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw)

mainloop()
```

Someone, please help.

Comment: Ive added an answer

Answer (score 1):

I have used a similar functionality in my GUI and I used `win32gui` at first, but realized it was overkill for this small purpose, instead, just go for `PyGetWindow` and `PIL`.

Start by installing the module, by saying this in the terminal.

```
pip install PyGetWindow
pip install Pillow
```

then, this code will take a screenshot automatically after 3 seconds

```
from tkinter import *
from win32gui import FindWindow, GetWindowRect
import pygetwindow as gw
from PIL import ImageGrab

def ss():
    win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Trial')[0]
    winleft = win.left+9
    wintop = win.top+38 #change 38 to 7 to not capture the titlebar
    winright = win.right-9
    winbottom = win.bottom-9
    final_rect = (winleft,wintop,winright,winbottom)
    img = ImageGrab.grab(final_rect)
    img.save('Required Image.png')
#making the tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Trial')

cv = Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg='white', cursor='cross')
cv.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

root.after(3000,ss)

root.mainloop()
```

Here, `win = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Title of the window')[0]`, you have to call your window name, like whatever the name of the window you set is, like, `root.title('Hello World')` then `'Title of the window'` would be replaced by `'Hello World'`. Or by default it will tkinter title will be `'tk'`.

Or if your still reluctant on using `win32gui` then replace your `ss()` to,

```
def ss():
    win = FindWindow(None, 'Title of the window')
    rect = GetWindowRect(win)
    list_rect = list(rect)
    list_frame = [-9, -38, 9, 9]
    final_rect = tuple((map(lambda x,y:x-y,list_rect,list_frame))) #subtracting two lists

    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=final_rect)
    img.save('Image.png')
```

Extra Tip:

- Why am i subtracting some amount from the pixels? its because, windows has decorations like drop shadow effect to the windows, which are also part of the windows and will be included in the screenshot, so i used this to get rid of those extra pixels,i guess it will make your neural network more efficient with no garbage items to look into.

Here is the image i got:

[image]

Hope this helped you, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Extra reference - [ImageGrab not grabbing precise bbox image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001826/imagegrab-not-grabbing-precise-bbox-image)

Cheers

Comment: Hi Cool Cloud, thank you very much for submitting an answer. The problem seems to be lying somewhere else, I have tried both of the methods you have submitted, and they all output the same as the original method I used. The image is always offset north-west of the canvas, (i.e. tkinter window). This is a rather unusual situation because it seems to be working for others, just not for myself. Once again, thanx for the answer :)

Comment: @Hamza Can you include your image with the Q and also, the whole tkinter window is not being captured?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by including my Image with the Q? Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow. Only a bit of the top-left of the Tkinter window is shown on the bottom right of the captured image, that also when the tkinter window is closer to the top left of my computer screen.

Comment: @Hamza You got an image captured by running the code right? You can attack images to question. Go ahead and edit the Q with this image, so i can assist further

Comment: I have attached the image to the question, sorry for the inconvenience :/

Comment: Yes, my original code and both of the code segments in your submitted answer give this output.

Comment: @Hamza Ive updated the answer now with your code, take a look once more

Comment: Hey Cool Cloud, thanx so much once again. However, I am still getting the same result. The problem seems to be lying somewhere else since every relevant method seems to be giving the same result, which is as in the question.

Comment: @Hamza Are the code included with the code, the only code your using?is there anything additional

Comment: It isn't the only code. I have a canvas, on which I can draw digits. When I click 'Recognize', I get the program to capture an image of the canvas using the code you provide and display the image for me. It always displays something like the image attached to the question.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the code from the whole file, in which I am building the Tkinter gui.

Comment: @Hamza take a look at what i got? the exact image i wanted, is what i got.

Comment: Whattttt, that's absurd. How is it different for me then?

Comment: @Hamza Could it be because your using a Mac? take a look at the first method, i removed the increments, maybe try it again

Comment: I tried again, it simply does not work. And no, I do not use a Mac, I use Windows

Comment: @Hamza Well, im not sure why, im out of ideas, it works in my system well and perfect.

Comment: this is rather strange, would you perhaps have any reasons for why this could be happening?

Comment: @Hamza I too use Vs code, so im not sure what exactly is leading to such behavior :(

Comment: Nevertheless, I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: @Hamza Keep trying and maybe hopefully youll find a solution, i gave the same code to a similar Q too and it worked well there.

Comment: All your approaches, even my initial approach, are likely supposed to work, yet something is causing the opposite

Comment: @Hamza can you try this on some other pc?

Comment: That would have been a good idea, but I don't have another machine to try this on.

Comment: @Hamza This could be due to some unusual "stuff" running in your pc maybe, dunno.